# Oracle: update a field only if condition is met

Tags: oracle

I want to update employee table column  value based on the date field  .

```
CREATE TABLE employee
( 
id number(10) NOT NULL,  
name varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
emp_cus number(10) , 
emp_btdate TIMESTAMP
);


INSERT INTO employee VALUES ( 9369 , 'Sameer' , 45 ,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I want to Update emp_cus  based on a condition

- Extract the year from the emp_btdate .
- if it is next year then  add 100 to it .
- Or else add 20 to the emp_cus value .

I have tried . need help on the WHEN Case

```
UPDATE
    employee
SET
    emp_cus = 
         CASE 
            WHEN  THEN emp_cus + 100 
           
            ELSE 20
         END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b588f4/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE employee
SET emp_cus = 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM emp_btdate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1
            THEN emp_cus + 100
        ELSE
            emp_cus + 20
    END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply , but I dont see any condtion like if its next year

Comment: @user21125892, you don't see the `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRUNC(.., 'year')` to get first day of a year, and add `INTERVAL '1' Year` to get next year from it.

```
UPDATE
    employee
SET
    emp_cus = 
         CASE 
            WHEN Trunc(emp_btdate, 'year') = Trunc(sysdate, 'year') + INTERVAL '1' Year 
              THEN emp_cus + 100 
            ELSE 20
         END
```